# Should I be binding also inbuilt React methods?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, binding, extension-methods

It is a common practice to be **`bind`** a user-created method inside a `React.Component` class.

```
class App extends React.Component { // simplified example, not actual code
   constructor(){ 
      //...
      this.logIn=this.logIn.bind(this) // Binding of a method
   }
}
```

Naturally, this is beceause we need to explicitly `bind` the method to "`this class`", otherwise we would be referencing with `this` the `window` object!

---

What's however unclear to me, least from the documentation and so on I viewed, **if we use in-built life-cycle methods** such as `render()` or **`componentDidMount()`**, majority of the code snippets and also the official documentation seem to **not explicitly `bind` to `this`**

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(){
      //....
      this.componentDidMount = this.componentDidMount.bind(this) 
      // is there reason why we don't do this ^ ??
   }
}
```

- Is there some in-built binding already inside the `React.Component` we extend?
- Or why don't we need to explicitly `bind` the life-cycle methods *(`componentDidMount()`)* like the rest of our created methods *(`logIn()`)*?

Comment: When will you ever call `componentDidMount` yourself anyway? The reason to bind the other ones is when you pass the function as a callback, if you didn't bind it it becomes unbound, but if you're never passing `this.componentDidMount` as a callback, there's no concern of that

Comment: If you want to test it, I suggest you make a component with a button, and set the onClick to `this.componentDidMount`, see what happens. Then you'll discover for yourself if it's bound or not. `<button onClick={this.componentDidMount}/>`

Comment: @TKoL Admittedly yeah, the bigger picture behind it did not occur to me that we would very seldom if ever actually callback the 'life-cycle methods'. Though theoretically speaking, it still is a valid a question as to why or if it's bound *(gonna check so myself now as you pointed out in the comment)*

Comment: Lifecycles methods are from parent class i.e. `React.Component`. as they are already binded in parent and you are just overriding them, you don't need to bind them again

Comment: Afaik those methods are bound because the React library doesn't use ES6 classes. Example code: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/fnjs468g/

Comment: I've checked myself and it doesn't look to be bound. But yes, it doesn't need to be bound because it's never passed to anything as a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made a component with the following:

```
...
componentDidMount() {
    var that = this;
    var x = 0;
}
...
render() {
    ....
    <button onClick={this.componentDidMount}>DID MOUNT</button>
    ....
}
```

And the results are in -- when the function does initially mount, `that` is properly bound, but when clicked from the button, it is not.

Which means that the componentDidMount is not already bound, but **it is called from the React internals with the proper context** so that it doesn't need to be bound.

-- edit

Perhaps also of note: it's worth checking if you use an autobind package, if that binds the lifecycle methods. `autobind-decorator` in fact does!

Answer (score -1):

> Naturally, this is beceause we need to explicitly bind the method to "this class", otherwise we would be referencing with this the window object!

You can also use arrow functions to been able to use this without binding:

```js
sayHello=()=>{
  return 'hello';
}

myOtherFunction=()=>{
  console.log('I can acces the other function! Say:'+ this.sayHello())
}
```

And you don't need to bind the  life-cycle methods

Edit: As the documentation says in https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

> You have to be careful about the meaning of this in JSX callbacks. In JavaScript, class methods are not bound by default. If you forget to bind this.handleClick and pass it to onClick, this will be undefined when the function is actually called.

So it is supposed that lifecycle methods are bound by default.

Comment: `And you don't need to bind the life-cycle methods` OP's questions is *why*, and this doesn't answer that.